# Cakephp 2.x Custom exception render

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, error-handling

This is so far what i have:

**app/Config/core.php**

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

**app/Config/bootstrap.php**

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array('bootstrap' => true));
```

**app/Plugin/Core/bootstrap.php**

```
Configure::write('Exception.renderer', 'Core.AppExceptionRenderer');
```

**app/Plugin/Core/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php**

```
App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function notFound($error) {
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }

    public function missingController($error) {
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Those simple echos work.

Now i want each error function to render (not redirect!) a view from `Core` plugin, like `app/Plugin/Core/View/Pages/error`.

I don't want to render a static page (`/Errors/error400.ctp` for example) because the content of the error page can be edited by the user from an admin panel.

The error page layout should be set in the theme called `Default`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are up to, set the layout & view to render in the beforeFilter method-

```
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->layout = 'YOUR_LAYOUT'; // Setting the default layout to your layout
        $this->view   = '../../Plugin/Core/View/Pages/error'; //Check this path to your ctp file
    }
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the view for the custom error like this

**app/Plugin/Core/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php**

```
<?php

App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function notFound($error) {
         $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'custom_errors', 'action' => 'not_found'));
    }

    public function missingController($error) {
         $this->controller->redirect(array('controller' => 'custom_errors', 'action' => 'missing_controller'));
    }
}
```

**app/Controllers/CustomErrorsController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class CustomErrorsController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter(){

    }

    public function not_found(){
        // your coding goes here.

    }

    public function missing_controller(){
        // your coding goes here.

    }
}
```

the you can specify the views for the actions.